# How to remove a programatically loaded reCAPTCHA V2?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, recaptcha, captcha

On an ajax-based or js-based website or a single page application you can call `grecaptcha.render('targetId', ...)` to create the reCAPTCHA element on demand.

But how can you remove it once the reCAPTCHA is no longer needed?

Creating and deleting the reCaptcha HTML by switching routes leads to a "memory leak".

I am looking for something like `reCaptcha.destroy()`.

Comment: Isn’t it enough to just hide it via CSS?

Comment: What if I want to have it appear at different places, depending on what the user is doing? I could try creating one and moving it to another parent though I'd expect this will break it.

Comment: Well then check if it already exists in place X, and if not add it …

Comment: Facing the same problem, I tried removing the reCAPTCHA (including the top-level `div` under `body` from the DOM after it was no longer needed. Unfortunately it seems that that's not the only spot in which reCAPTCHA leaks memory.